# Attachment sent via AWS SES not visible on iphone

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, email-attachments, amazon-ses

Our service send email with attachment which is not visible on ios devices.

AWS team suggested to add double quotes around file name but when i try to add ", MimeBodyPart turning into escape character.

```
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(Base64.getMimeDecoder()
.decode(attachment.getAttachment()), attachment.getContentType()));
messageBodyPart.setFileName("\""+ attachment.getName()+"\"");
```

> From: donotreply@abc.com To: test@abc.com Message-ID:
>   <962944318.2.1571250351443@[10.200.78.179]> Subject: subject for test 
>   MIME-Version: 1.0  Content-Type: multipart/related;
>   boundary="----=_Part_1_977674685.1571250351337"
>
> ------=_Part_1_977674685.1571250351337   Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>   boundary="----=_Part_0_474488818.1571250351334"
>
> ------=_Part_0_474488818.1571250351334   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8  Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>
> Hi your email send is success
>   ------=_Part_0_474488818.1571250351334--
>
> ------=_Part_1_977674685.1571250351337   Content-Type: application/pdf; name="\"myData.pdf\""   Content-Transfer-Encoding:
>   base64  Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="\"myData.pdf\""
>
> ICAgICAgICAgDXhyZWYNNCAxMQ0wMDAwMDAwMDE2IDAwMDAwIG4NCjAwMDAwMDA2NjAgMDAwMDAg
>   ------=_Part_1_977674685.1571250351337--

Comment: Does mail client on ios atleast show there is an attachment and couldn't open the attachment ? or you don't see attachment at all in received email ?

Comment: It shows that there's an attachment but when i open the email i dont see one. I can open the attachment in the iCloud web interface it just IOS mail app that is having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found fix, issue was with respect to content-type. changing content-type to multipart/mixed resolved it.